# How to choose an area for color picker in Paint.Net

Tags: colors, paint.net

This is quite beginner question. I want to choose right color of some area because the thing i want to get color is not homogeneous area. How can i choose some area with color picker in paint.net ?

Comment: this is for SO.

Comment: @soandos how so? It has nothing to do with programming, and is about using a piece of software ([Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/))

Comment: @Freshblood you can only choose a single color at once. Are you trying to get an "average" color for an area or what? You can't have an "area" of color selected to then fill something else with.

Comment: Apologies. was mixed up.

Comment: @nhinkle - Yes, you are right. I want to get avarage color of an area.Sorry for late answer

Comment: No problem @Freshblood. If you could edit your question to clarify that, it would be helpful to people trying to answer. Do check out Ben Jones's answer below; it looks like he may have figured out a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my trick that works, some of the time, in these cases:

1. Using lasso selection or magic wand (playing with the tolarance) I select an existing area with the color area that I want. (It doesn't need to be perfect, but preferably bigger than the area you are looking to fill).
2. CTRL+C (copy) the selected area.
3. Create a new layer.
4. Paste the selected area into the new layer.
5. Remove the areas until it looks like it blends well. Blurring the whole layer also help get rid of some of the pixelation difference between layers.
6. (Optional) Merge the layers once you have something you like.

I know this is considerable more work and is more of an art than a science, but it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Execuse... I thought this is quite beginner question.

Comment: I wish it was, but what you are trying to do is actually not so beginner. Congrats! You are no longer a beginner if you find a way to solve your problem! ;-)